# Undo "remember my decision" in eclipse for team synchronizing perspective

Tags: eclipse, perspective, synchronization

I clicked with the rigth button of mouse in one project.
Then I clicked in the menu: `Compare with --> Head Revision` (using git)
Then I clicked in `Remember my decision` to always open `team synchronizing` perspective.

But I dont want to alwas open team synchronizing perspective.
How can I undo this action?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are after the following preference:

[image: open perspective automatically]

To access, `Window | Preferences | Team` and change the `Open the associated perspective when a synchronize operation completes` setting to the desired value.

Answer (score 3):

With in the Synchronize view, select the menu and select Preferences

[image]

In the preferences, set the highlighted setting back to prompt for being prompted before switching perspective

[image]

Click ok and you'll get what you want